# hadoop key returns multiple values

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera

This is my first time programming in Hadoop and I'm basing my assignment off of WordCount v1.0 on the hadoop tutorial website.

Assignment: You have two files. File0 contains every word in the dictionary. File1 contains one random word. For example: 'beautiful'.

And when I run the program it should return every word in File0 that is the same size as the word in File1

*beautiful will return every 9 letter word in the dictionary

For example: 
beautiful - AARDVARKS AASVOGELS ABAMPERES....ZYMOGRAMS ZYMURGIES

So my question is how should I go about this? The hadoop wordcount v1.0 returns the key and a single value. ---- e.g. (beautiful 4)

Do I need to change the value from an int to a string or maybe some sort of an array that contains every word of the same size as the key?

*basically I need to change the format from

(beautiful 4)

to

(beautiful: AARDVARKS AASVOGELS ABAMPERES...ZYMOGENES ZYMOGRAMS ZYMURGIES)

Here is the code (from their website):

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount {

  public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      String line = value.toString();
      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
      while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        output.collect(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      int sum = 0;
      while (values.hasNext()) {
        sum += values.next().get();
      }
      output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
    conf.setJobName("wordcount");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
  }
}
```

Do I need to change the map, reduce, or both?? And how??

can someone please help! thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

In the reducer instead of doing a sum in the loop, use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and append together a string of words that match the random word's length.  You may also have to change your OutputValueClass in your main method from IntWritable to Text. you will also need to change your reducer to implement:

```
Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text>
```

Also in the mapper instead of writing one as the value in the output write the length of the word.

Happy coding